# bootstrap with DataTables not stacking properly

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="height: 512px">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="firstDiv"></div>
            <div class="dataTablesWrapper">
                <table id="myDataTable">
                   <thead></thead>
                   <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-3 thirdDiv"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to put my datatable within a col-sm-9 class so that it is responsive and will stack when resized. What happens though is that it stacks above my col-sm-3 class div and blocks it. I can't seem to find any examples about how to structure dataTables so that it is responsive. What I want is something like this:

```
   col-sm-9     col-sm-3
------------- -------------
| firstDiv  | | thirdDiv  |
| height:50%| |height:100%| 
------------- |           |
------------- |           |
| dataTable | |           |
| height:50%| |           |
------------- -------------
```

height is a percentage of the row height.

I want the ".thirdDiv" will stack beneath the firstDiv and dataTable. Currently it stacks behind the dataTable.

Answer (score 0):

Create two .row classes inside col-sm-9 and put your first div and datatable on each row.

```
Here is the sample
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/AkkEoStEIVaJGL5I3E4I?p=preview